# How to use pointers to structures

Tags: c

I have defined a structure in one of my source code files. Also I have defined pointer to that structure like (global declaration)

`struct blockPropStruct
    {   int random_id;
        int id;
        CvPoint left_up;
        CvPoint right_down;
                };`

`typedef struct blockPropStruct *newBlock;`

In the same file I am assigning memory to those pointers using malloc to create array of structures.

`newBlock = (blockPropStruct*)malloc(maxNum*sizeof(blockPropStruct));`

Now I am trying yo use it in some other source file by declaring (global declaration)

`extern struct blockPropStruct *newBlock;`

Now when I use something like

`newBlock[i].left_up.x=mark1[i];`

It throws up an error.

Comment: do we have to guess the error or can you tell us what it was?

Comment: If I have to guess I'd say you need to declare an array extern struct blockPropStruct newBlock[]

Comment: error C2036: 'blockPropStruct *' : unknown size

Comment: @David still the same situation

Comment: error C2027: use of undefined type 'blockPropStruct'

Comment: you need to define the type!!

Comment: Please clarify what else need to be added

Comment: the compiler says not. You have to define the struct in each file that references a variable of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you have omitted the declaration of the struct type in the file which declares the extern variable.

Comment: is the struct definition in a header file that is included in all the source files?

Comment: no struct is defined in a source file 'parameterinitialization.cpp' which included in my project.

Comment: i did it . And it worked. But please tell why. I was doing the same thing with arrays and it was working but why in this case i have to include the defination in some header file

Comment: @bubble: `parameterinitialization.cpp`... that file name doesn't suggest that this is **C** code as you have tagged in your question...  If you were mixing C and C++ code, then you should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Jeff okay but i guess thats not the real problem

Comment: the arrays were probably for built in types so the compiler knows how they are laid out in memory. For a struct the compiler needs to know the struct layout when you start accessing fields etc.

Comment: @bubble it's the details like whether it's C or C++ that really matter and in this case it makes a huge difference to the way we try to answer. All the answers about struct type definitions are predicated on the language being C.

Comment: @David also when I access the elements of my structure in the same file in which I declared it, it works fine. I have to put it in some header file only when I have to include it in some other source files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks David.. At this point of time I realize how novice my question was then..

Answer (score 2):

The name of your structure is `struct blockPropStruct`.  Note that in C, you can't just remove the `struct` part, it's part of the type's name.  You can define a type for your structure so you have less typing, but I think it's better to remember to use your structures as `struct blockPropStruct`.

Based on the error messages you have added in your comments:

> error C2036: 'blockPropStruct *' : unknown size
>   error C2027: use of undefined type 'blockPropStruct'

You are attempting to get the size `sizeof(blockPropStruct)` in your `malloc()` call since `blockPropStruct` is not a valid identifier so you are attempting to get the size of an undefined type.

To define your type:

```
typedef struct blockPropStruct blockPropStruct;
```

Now you can refer to your structure type as `blockPropStruct` or `struct blockPropStruct`.

Comment: @David - it does. `error C2027: use of undefined type 'blockPropStruct'` means the compiler doesn't recognize `blockPropStruct` so he needs to typedef's it.

Comment: @David: Was working that in as the comments came in.  I had my hunch but I didn't know for sure so I couldn't include that initially.

Comment: ok, I took OP at his word that the error was in the file with the extern

Comment: malloc file gets compiled perfectly

Comment: @bubble: I suggest you post all relevant code snippets then.  Everything you have shown and described to us in code and the errors you are getting are not related at all.  And make sure it is all up to date, otherwise you're just confusing us and we won't be able to adequately help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name with 'typedef' and point to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
newBlock = (blockPropStruct*)malloc(maxNum*sizeof(blockPropStruct));
```

To actually for the above statement to work, the current source file should see the size of structure. So, check whether you have included the corresponding header file.

---

```
extern struct blockPropStruct *newBlock;
```

And when you are doing -

```
newBlock[i].left_up.x=mark1[i];
```

You should bring the definition of the `blockPropStruct` to the current compilation unit to be able to use it members. So, try -

```
#include "blockPropStruct.h"
extern struct blockPropStruct *newBlock;  // This says to use else where 
                                          // initialized newBlock
// ....
newBlock[i].left_up.x=mark1[i];           // And to do this, bring the definition
                                          // to this file scope
```

And there is no need to explicitly typecast `malloc`.

Comment: From reading the question, I'd say that 'blockPropStruct' isn't defined / included from a header file, which is where the problems coming from...